# Ssh authentication works, but git clone doesn't

Tags: windows, windows-10, ssh, git, clone

I am on Windows 10 and I'm really confused why I can't clone a repo from bitbucket. I generated a keypair and added the public key to my bitbucket account, added the private key to the ssh-agent. `ssh-add -l` shows: C:\Users\"username"\.ssh\id_rsa (RSA) which is the right key. Now even trying to connect to bitbucket with ssh using: `ssh -vT git@bitbucket.org` returns among many other lines:

```
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\<username>/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'bitbucket.org' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\<username>/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:9CVIiWqSy1eKuUS7yhmwum6VgKrW/tJE0/T2PWdAWmQ C:\\Users\\<username>/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
**debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).**
Authenticated to bitbucket.org ([18.205.93.2]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
logged in as <user>

You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled
```

but then when I try to clone my repo: `git clone <repo_url copy pasted from bitbucket directly>` I get:

```
Cloning into '<repo_name>'...
git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

looking at the settings of the repo I do have write rights. I really don't know what exactly is going wrong... Any ideas? Https works, so it can't be a permission issue.
But I would like to use ssh.
What is weird is that key_load_public does not find the key, even though it exists, but then later on the authentication still succeeds for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that, you might have added the access keys which are available in the settings specific to the repository which you are trying to clone. They provide read-only access to your repository. See the image below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKgMi.png)

Make sure you have added the ssh keys in your Bitbucket account settings and check again.

Comment: I think this is more of a comment than really an answer, since it asks for clarification. But no my keys are under my account, and work for all projects.